Lemniscate of Bernoulli using Watt's linkage
The lemniscate of Bernoulli is a curve which can be defined as all points $P$ with $\overline{PA} \cdot \overline{PB}=2c$ with two given points $A$ and $B$ at distance 2c (see wikipedia).
One way to construct this is using a Watt's linkage. I found the following construction with ${\displaystyle \overline{AC}=\overline{BD}={\sqrt {2}}a, \overline{CD}=2a}$ (see picture below). $E$ is the middle of $CD$.
So I tried to prove that $\overline{PA} \cdot \overline{PB}=xy=\text{const.}$ but failed. I include a Geogebra-file at the bottom.
I've tried to use the law of cosine but got
$x^2=3a^2-2\sqrt{2}a^2 \cos(t)$ and $y^2=3a^2-2\sqrt{2}a^2 \cos(s)$.
Can somebody explain how to prove that $\overline{PA} \cdot \overline{PB}=xy=\text{const.}$?
(Similar question)



I'll use your numbers, with $a=1$ and consequently $AB=2$.
Set up then a cartesian frame such that $A=(-1,0)$, $B=(1,0)$ and:
$$
C=(-1+\sqrt2\cos\theta,\sqrt2\sin\theta),
\quad
D=(1+\sqrt2\cos\phi,\sqrt2\sin\phi).
$$
Of course angle $\phi$ depends on $\theta$. To find this relation we use that $CD^2=4$, which leads to the equation:
$$
\sqrt2(\cos\phi-\cos\theta)-\cos\phi\cos\theta-
\sin\phi\sin\theta+1=0.
$$
This can be seen as a linear equation for $\sin\phi$ and $\cos\phi$: combining it with $\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi=1$ we get the solution:
$$
\cos\phi=\frac{2 \sqrt{2}-3\cos\theta}{2 \sqrt{2}\cos\theta-3},
\quad
\sin\phi=\frac{\sin\theta}{2 \sqrt{2}\cos\theta-3}
$$
(the other solution $\phi=\theta$ must of course be discarded).
Now we can compute the coordinates of point $E=(C+D)/2$ and the distances
$$
AE^2=\frac{1}{3-2 \sqrt{2}\cos\theta},
\quad
BE^2={3-2 \sqrt{2}\cos\theta},
$$
giving $AE\cdot BE=1$.
